# Running headless server on Windows via SSH

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh

I'm currently working on a software project that allows remote installation via SSH. I transfer a small installer, and then a zipped archive of the main application. The installer will unzip the transmitted package and I am stuck on the part where I actually want to execute the application in the background. On Linux everything works perfectly with the *nohup* command and after some research I found that this is normally done via the start command on Windows but I cannot get it to work. If I run start calc.exe as a test it works and the process shows up in the tasklist (no GUI though) but if I try to run my own .exe with **start "" "app.exe" "-master"** I don't get any feedback at all. Are there any reliable alternatives to the start command? The process has to be independent from the SSH session because it is supposed to run for a long time. Also the test with start calc.exe was only successful on a remote host(Windows 7 VM). If I tried to reproduce the results on localhost(Windows) which I mostly use for testing as of right now for convenience reasons, it also failed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access over SSH to remote windows computer, do reverse forwarded tunnel for RDP as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1344168/164837) and login normally to GUI session. If you wouldn't logout but simply terminate SSH tunnel or disconnect from RDP without logout then your session will be active with all programs you started there.

If you can't setup reverse tunnel, you can use another solution:
run program in session 0 via task scheduler. You can set up your task via terminal with help of `schtasks.exe`. In this case you can only communicate with your program over IPC, message loop or via files