# Remote USB device (gamepad, specifically) over RDP or similar, over internet (not LAN)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, vpn, remote-desktop

The goal is to have two Windows devices, A and B, on separate networks where router admin privileges may not be accessible; Device A connects a gamepad (e.g. Xbox One controller) via USB, then connects to Device B *over the internet* via RDP (or some similar remote client), so that a user on Device A can control the desktop of Device B with the gamepad, and Device B will recognize the gamepad as if it were a locally-connected USB device. (note: Device B *will* be attended)

I know Microsoft has an [RDP gamepad plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/RdpGamepad), and I also know exposing RDP to the internet is a terrible idea, security-wise. I've heard a VPN tunnel can help with the security aspect, but I don't know how to do implement that. I also know there are some [programs that can remotely share a USB device](https://alternativeto.net/software/usb-redirector/?platform=windows), but they're all proprietary and paid, and I'm very much hoping for a fully FOSS implementation.

#### Can anyone explain a way to do this that either…

1. Allows RDP to connect securely across the internet, without requiring admin router/firewall access,
2. Connects the devices via VPN in a way that allows the gamepad to be recognized by Device B, or
3. Uses some other solution I haven't thought of, preferably that doesn't require paid software or hardware?

P.S. If a VPN is a way to go, does this have to be from a paid company, or is self-hosting an option?

Comment: This answer (https://superuser.com/a/1344168/876852) may be a solution by doing RDP via SSH, but I don't understand it conceptually, and unfortunately the grammar errors make it hard to parse. Can anyone explain this in simpler terms?

Comment: For VMs you could use [spice](https://www.spice-space.org), but I don't know if there is an implementation for bare metal installations

Comment: @mashuptwice could you explain how a VM would help? In this scenario, both Device A and Device B are physical computers.